# What are versioned branches on GitHub?

Tags: github, dvcs, branching-and-merging

On GitHub, sometimes I see projects with "1.x" and "2.x" branches, in addition to tags. Take the [Grails SpringSec plugin](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-core) for example. It has both a `master` and `1.x` branch, as well as several tags.

This has me curious:

- At what point would these "1.x" and "2.x" (etc.) "version branches" be created? At what point would they be merged back with `master`?
- At what point would artifacts be built from these "version branches"? In other words, "1.x" could mean "1.0.0" or "1.5.29"...but the latest version might be "1.7.14". What's the relation between the "1.x" branch and the "1.7.14" version of the binary (JAR, ZIP, whatever)?
- If you're already going to go with "version branches", then what purpose would a tag possibly serve?

Comment: Why the closevote? This isn't a dupe, shows research, and is a programming question.

Comment: Probably because Git supports any number of workflows, so this is dangerously close to being "primarily opinion-based".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a brief explanation of how branches and tags work and how best to use them.

**1. Branches**

Branches provide a means to separate your code into different development streams. Initially you start with one main branch (be it `master`, `trunk` or other common names). As your project evolves, you start needing certain stability while developing.

A good way to guarantee this is to start using more than one branch for your work. Consider the following: you're working on a feature whose development effort would be high and/or long-term. You wouldn't want to have this in your main branch, if it's something that will change the behavior of your currently existing code, as while it's work-in-progress, you might break things for other people. So, this is when you normally create feature (or topic) branches. When your code becomes stable enough, you merge your feature branch with the respective master. This approach helps you work in isolation from the rest of the developers. They can check your work and comment on it, propose fixes and all at the same time while keeping your `master` stable.

**2. Tags**

Tags are something to be considered permanent. They are a marker of your code at a given point in time. When you release version `1.2.3`, you need to be able to tell ***exactly*** what was in this release, if somebody reports a bug, so that you would be able to reproduce it easily and also check if it has been resolved during development at a later stage when you've released newer versions.

**3. Working With Branches And Releasing From Them**

Consider you have multiple clients. Assume `ClientA` has a contract with you that they will pay to use version `1.2.3`, while `ClientB` is a new client interested in your ground-breaking work on some feature in version `2.x` that `ClientA` isn't all hyped up about and therefore not so willing to upgrade to. Your contract states that each client gets service for a year after their payment for your licenses. Yes, generally companies should push for their clients to upgrade to newer versions of their product/service, but quite often the clients are large institutions in which the pace of work and decision-taking is much slower than desired.

So, in order to be able to support both clients, you need to make sure that you have a proper branching strategy and that you will be able to work in isolation. This normally means you have a main branch like master on which all your bleeding-edge development is done. When certain features are ready, if they are needed on the respective branches for those clients, they are merged to their branches. So, if you have `feature-15` developed on `master` and it's something that is needed for `ClientB`, you only merge it to their branch. If `ClientA` has reported a critical issue which seems to be only relevant to their product version and not reproducible in later versions, you apply a fix just for them and rollout a release.

Quite often, your contracts are such that you don't give your clients certain functionality, unless they've paid for it. Your pricing model could be annual service which covers free upgrades for the whole year, covering minor and major version. You could also have some clients which you've signed a few years ago and who are very slow at upgrading and thus this need for keeping different version lines alive for a longer period.

**3.1. Branching and Tagging In a Multi-branch Environment**

Consider you have the following branches:

- `master` : latest development (3.x)
- `1.x` : for your clients who insist on using older versions of your code
- `2.x` : for a bit more up-to-date clients.

Branch `1.x` will be used for releasing `1.x-SNAPSHOT`-s; `2.0` for `2.x-SNAPSHOT` and the master -- for your yet unreleased work on 3.x. Normally, it's a good idea to have a branch per major version which you are actively supporting. For minors you would branch off that branch (for example, version 2.0.3 would be off branch `2.0.x`). When your work on a given iteration of features is considered done and stable enough, you create a tag off that branch for the version under development and you bump the version of your current development to the next minor version. I'm talking abstractly, as you haven't mentioned what build tool you're using. With Maven, for example, the version currently under development would be a `SNAPSHOT` and if your currently released one was from branch `2.x` and your development version was `2.3-SNAPSHOT`, then your newly released version would be `2.3` and your next development version would be `2.4-SNAPSHOT`.

I hope this all makes more sense now.

Comment: You call this a "brief" explanation? `;)`

Comment: Well, it's brief from the point of view of a build and release engineer like myself! :D

Answer (score 0):

First of all the `1.x` branch is technically just a branch name, like `dev`, `aFeature` or any other string.

This is a different model of version control. For example it makes sense, if you sell different licences for different versions.

In this model, you normally don't merge the branches back into the master. You start these branches if you start a new version. Then you maintain them parallel to the master branch.

You then build your releases (you called them artifacts) directly on those branches, by setting "Tags". After that you can go on developing on the same branch. For example:
We create a branch `2.x`. After developing a while on that branch, we just create a Tag `2.1.0` and go on developing on that branch. After some bug fixes on the same branch a Tag `2.1.1` and so on. The same work is done for branch `3.x` and `4.x`.

So the purpose of the Tags is, to *freeze* a certain state of the code and provide it to the end users.

Comment: Versioned branches aren't just named branches as time in package.json file we usually write in dependencies for example ` "express": "^4.17.1"` which means from version 4.17.1 above. In other words they are like increasing numbers not strings